# Scrollviewer issue in windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In a page 20 controls need to place.so that i taken scrollviewer and placed grid inside that scrollviewer.inside the grid placed all controls.while running the app the controls are scroll up and down but i am not able to enter text in below controls of page because it's scrolling up not able to keep stable to enter the below controls text.it's suddenly down all controls....

```
 <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid  Name="grid1">
                    <Image Height="944" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="486" Source="/MyBuddies;component/Images/registerbg.png" Margin="0,1,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Height="51" Margin="127,17,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Registration" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontFamily="Verdana" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,83,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="First Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" FontSize="24" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,68,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox2" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287" FontSize="24" WatermarkText="Enter Firstname" BorderBrush="#BF000000"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,144,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Last Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" FontSize="24" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,130,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox1" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" WatermarkText="Enter Lastname" Width="285" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,206,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="User Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" FontSize="24" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,193,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox3" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" WatermarkText="Enter UserName" Width="286" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,270,0,0" Name="textBlock5" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <PasswordBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,259,0,0" Name="passwordBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="284" BorderBrush="#BF000000" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,339,0,0" Name="textBlock6" Text="Confirm Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <PasswordBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,324,0,0" Name="passwordBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="283" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,406,0,0" Name="textBlock7" Text="Email" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" FontSize="24" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,389,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox4" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" WatermarkText="Enter Email" Width="281" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,473,0,0" Name="textBlock8" Text="Gender" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <RadioButton Content="Male" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="191,453,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" />
                    <RadioButton Content="Female" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="317,453,0,0" Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,530,0,0" Name="textBlock9" Text="Age" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" FontSize="24" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,510,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox5" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" WatermarkText="Enter Age" Width="283" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,587,0,0" Name="textBlock10" Text="City" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" FontSize="24" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,576,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox6" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" WatermarkText="Enter City" Width="280" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,658,0,0" Name="textBlock11" Text="Country" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" FontSize="24" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,641,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox7" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" WatermarkText="Enter Country" Width="280" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,727,0,0" Name="textBlock12" Text="User Image" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <Image Height="83" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,716,0,0" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" Source="/MyBuddies;component/Images/registerphoto.png" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,861,0,0" Name="textBlock13" Text="User Image" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
                    <my:WatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="#BF000000" FontSize="24" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,852,0,0" Name="watermarkTextBox8" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" WatermarkText="Enter Country" Width="280" />
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through this example we have to do some manual works as this issue is because of the default property of keyboard in wp7

http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/

Comment: i am facing the issue was when scroll up the screen trying to enter the at last textbox.i am not able to enter because suddenly moving down the screen.why the screen is not able to stable ?